# Reading element in harness provider block

Tags: terraform, logic, infrastructure-as-code, harness

I have following json

```
 {
   "applications": [
     {"abc": {"app": "myapp", "org": "myorg_a"}},
     {"bcd": {"app": "myapp2", "org": "myorg_b"}}
   ]
 }
```

I need org = "myorg_a" in harness provider block https://registry.terraform.io/providers/harness/harness/latest/docs

```
#Configure the Harness provider for Next Gen resources
 provider "harness" {
    endpoint         = "https://app.harness.io/gateway"
    account_id       = myorg_a
    platform_api_key = "mike"
 }
```

I need to read myorg_a dynamically since tomorrow json may change to myorg_c. I need help to achieve it.

Using (data.http.myapi.body).applications.abc.org  I can read myorg_a but can't hardcode abc.

When I tried  (data.http.myapi.body).applications[0]["org"] I get error "The given key does not identify an element in this collection value. An object only supports looking up attributes by name, not by numeric index."

Comment: I don't think you can do that dynamically, but if you tell us where the values are coming from it might be easier to answer.

Comment: its read using (data.http.myapi.body).applications. I can read it using (data.http.myapi.body).applications.abc.org but tomorrow abc may not be there in json. So I need index or other way to read it.
I tried (data.http.myapi.body).applications[0]["org"] doesn't work.

Comment: Please add any errors to the question as well.

Answer (score 0):

I created this proposal using local variable and flattened that object using a nested iteration.

```
locals {
  data =  {
   "applications": [
     {"abc": {"app": "myapp", "org": "myorg_a"}},
     {"bcd": {"app": "myapp2", "org": "myorg_b"}}
   ]
 }
 data_org = flatten([ for k,v in local.data["applications"] : [
         for x,z in v :[
          {org = z.org}
         ]
  
 ]])

}
```

#### output for testing

```
output "get_values" {
  value = local.data_org
}
```

[image]